# WeightedAdjacencyMatrix does not complete for Connected Graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, markov-process

Please see code snippet below - I have a weighted, connected graph that models a software process using a `DiscreteMarkovProcess`.  I set some of the edge weights to zero to "turn off" some of the paths.  The code below removes the zero weight edges then deletes the nodes that have been "unconnected" - the resulting graph is connected , but when I try to generate a `WeightedAdjacentcyMatrix` - the function fails.  Any ideas ?

```
wam = WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[theModel]

EdgeCount[theModel]           (* 1507 *)
VertexCount[theModel]         (* 1052 *)
ConnectedGraphQ[theModel]     (* True *)

edgeCleanG = Fold[
   EdgeDelete[#1, #2[[1]]] &,
   theModel,
   Select[
    Transpose[{EdgeList[theModel], PropertyValue[theModel, EdgeWeight]}],
    #[[2]] == 0 &]
  ];

vertCleanG = VertexDelete[edgeCleanG, Map[#[[1]]&, Drop[ConnectedComponents[edgeCleanG],1]]];

EdgeCount[vertCleanG]         (* 1109 *)
VertexCount[vertCleanG]       (*  782 *)
ConnectedGraphQ[vertCleanG]   (* True *)

wam = WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[vertCleanG]
(* Out: WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[...] *)
```

Comment: It may be hard to say without `theModel`, or at least some toy example that behaves like it...

Comment: Please upload your variable theModel